# Changing color of nav item (dropdown - click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever I click this nav-item and click somewhere else, or the page I select opens up the nav item background-color changes to this white color. I've searched everywhere and tried a lot of tricks. Nothing works.

Here is a gif to show a clear example.

[image]

The website is setuped on a local server. Therefore, I can't give any links

I use bootstrap.

However, the divs & classes being used for this navbar are:

```
<div class="header-column">
    <div class="header-row">
        <div class="header-nav">
        <div class="header-nav-main header-nav-main-effect-1 header-nav-main-sub-effect-1 collapse">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">
```

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Can you post a a link? Are you using any libraries?

Comment: Can you post some code that replicates the issue? No way for us to tell what's going on just from a screenshot.

Comment: Yea, code is needed but may be related to pseudo such as visited, focus or active.

Comment: Added some lines might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a:link - a normal, unvisited link
a:visited - a link the user has visited
a:hover - a link when the user mouses over it
a:active - a link the moment it is clicked

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: red;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: hotpink;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b><a href="default.asp" target="_blank">This is a link</a></b></p>
<p><b>Note:</b> a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited in the CSS definition in order to be effective.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> a:active MUST come after a:hover in the CSS definition in order to be effective.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After changing the background color using the link selector it works & fixes the problem, but then hover background changes doesn't work. Like it's solid color whenever you try to click/hover it.

Comment: Interesting ... it must work.. here link that may help you: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Comment: Gord, I know how to fix this right now. Thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

You can test this.

```
.nav-pills > li {
    background-color:transparent !important;
}

.nav-pills > li > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li > a:focus,
.nav-pills > li > a:active {
    background-color:#2e353e;
}
```

Comment: After adding this, nothing happens.